# I cannot add email validation to MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using .Net Framework 4.0 and trying to build MVC. I tried to add Email validation by the code below

```
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
public string EMAIL_ADRESS { get; set; }
```

But it doesnt compile. It gives the error "The type or namespace name 'Email' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`EmailAddressAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.emailaddressattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) is defined in the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace inside the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll` assembly and is available only in .NET 4.5.

So here's checklist:

1. You are targeting .NET 4.5
2. You have referenced the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll` assembly inside the project you are writing this code in
3. You have brought the correct namespace in scope by adding a `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;` to the top of your file

It seems that number 3 in my checklist is not satisfied. That's the reason why this attribute is not available for you.

You could use a standard regular expression validator instead if you cnnot retarget your project to use .NET 4.5:

```
[RegularExpression("Some magic regex you can google out to validate an email address", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
public string EMAIL_ADRESS { get; set; }
```

Also I would recommend you sticking to standard C# conventions when naming your properties and use `EmailAddress` instead of `EMAIL_ADRESS`.

Answer (score 0):

As Darin pointed out you have to use `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`namespace,

you can also use `EmailAttribute` instead of `EmailAddress`

```
[Email(ErrorMessage = "Invalid email")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Comment: Could you point to the `EmailAttribute` class on MSDN? I wasn't familiar that such attribute exists.